# SSH with chroot and only working "sftp", "rsync" (both)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp, chroot

I have two users and one shared folder in my Ubuntu server:

1. User `writer`, which has write access to `/var/shared`. It's an application regularly making file changes in this folder from remote, with an SSH key.
2. User `reader` is used by multiple clients with an SSH key, a key they can get without my permission, that's why I need to restrict commands available in this shell.

#### Question:

I need to restrict commands accessible for the `reader` user so it can use only sftp and rsync protocols (no standard commands like `mkdir`, `ls`, `top`, ...). 
Only directory `/var/shared` must be readable, and must be a root path,
e.g., no need to `cd` into it, it's already `/` in sftp or rsync.

**How do I write a shell script so I can apply it with `usermod -s` for user `reader` that will give such behavior?** I cannot find any samples. How do I make `writer` also remain "jailed" to `/var/share`, so paths are same?

#### Notes:

1. I have tried `sshd_config`'s `Match`, `ForceCommand internal-sftp` and `ChrootDirectory` directives already. This requires the `ChrootDirectory` to be owned by root and non-writable (755 or less), and does not support `rsync`.
2. I have tried `rssh`, but it simply doesn't work for directories outside the home directory for the logged in user. So I couldn't chroot users to the same directory with different permissions.
3. I tried to use `command=".." ssh-rsa....` in the `authorized_keys` file, but didn't get how can I enable behavior which I need, I only check `rrsync` script from rsync's docs. This method has no `chroot` feature I need.

#### Can I  have a sample  at least for such shells? Is this achievable with scripts?

Bash and C++ (if needed) are welcome. Output of `ldd /bin/bash`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7e9d1000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f79dfd8b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f79dfb87000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f79df7bd000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bd0767c000)
```

Comment: You are almost there. The `755` permissions are a must, if you want a secure chroot, regardless technology. Then if you skip force command, you should be able to copy required binaries  with dependencies into the chroot (`rsync`, `sftp`). But much easier would be to allow only one (`sftp` preferably).

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ChrootDirectory` must be owned by root and not writable by other users. Thus `/var/shared` in your case cannot be `ChrootDirectory` value.

I would recommend to create a directory which would be writable by root only and make `/var/shared` accessible inside this dir either via Linux bind-mounting or some kind of symlinks workarounds.

If you need restrict `sftp` or `rsync`, you need to check `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable on the server with help of a "wrapper" enforced either via `ForceCommand` or via `command` in ssh public key, this variable is populated after user is authenticated and contains info what kind of connection clients is going to establish. For `sftp` it would have `sftp-server` inside, for `rsync` it would have `rsync`, for just `ssh` session it would have, IIRC, the variable empty, for `ssh date` it would be `date`. `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is run under authenticated user on the server!

This could be your start of the wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu
set -o pipefail

[[ -z "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-}" ]] && exit 1

case "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" in
    "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server")
        exec /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
        ;;
    "rsync --server"*)
        exec ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}
        ;;
    *)
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

As you can see, `ssh -v` gives you info about what command would be executed by the server. Thus you can change `/tmp` to something else in your wrapper as well.

```
$ rsync -a -e "ssh -v" bin localhost:/tmp/ 2>&1 | grep '^debug.*Sending command:'
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -logDtpre.iLsfxC . /tmp/
```